# not able to format json data to use it in auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I wanted to use autocomplete in a text box,I am making an ajax call to get the JSON and I wanted to use it to auto-complete the text box tags,but the array items are turning out to be [object object].and hence the id attribute of the JSON is inaccessible,I wanted to know if there are any ways to get out of this problem

```
var items;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#header").load("Header.html");
  $("#footer").load("Footer.html");

 var url= "GetAuthorities.do";
      $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
        tags: "mount rainier",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
      })
        .done(function( data ) {
            items=data;
        });

 $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source:items,
        label:items.id,
        value:items.value
})

});


<td width="30%"><input type="text" name="IrbAppNum" id="IrbAppNum" style="width:40%"> <input id="tags"></td>
```

After ajax call i am getting this JSON:

```
[[
  {"id":"1","value":"Stanford University"},
  {"id":"2","value":"University of Houston"},
  {"id":"3","value":"FDA"},
  {"id":"4","value":"Drug Authority of Texas"}
]]
```

Comment: which autocomplete widget you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `.done()` handler a bit as follows:

```
var items;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#header").load("Header.html");
    $("#footer").load("Footer.html");

    var url= "GetAuthorities.do";
    $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
        tags: "mount rainier",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        if(data && data.length > 0){
            items=data[0]; //grab the data which is at index 0

            //init the autocomplete widget here
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source:items,
                label:items.id,
                value:items.value
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here we are assigning the returned data to `items` variable by reading the index 0 of received object and also initiating the `autocomplete` widget there itself as its a `ajax` async call. Defining it outside of `.done` handler will have `items` variable undefined and you won't get anything in your autocomplete text box's search result.

Comment: thanks vijay your suggestions made me move the autocomplete code inside the done block and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
items=data;
```

to

```
items=data[0];
```

Comment: I'm not sure what data format the autocomplete function is expecting, but at least that will get you closer to your actual data

Answer (score 0):

use

```
items=data[0];
```

Since its Array of array of objects (2d array).
and *source* requires array of objects only.

Answer (score 0):

```
 working code:

 var items;
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#header").load("Header.html");
 $("#footer").load("Footer.html");
 var flickerAPI = "GetAuthorities.do";
  $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
        items=data[0];
        $("#overSightAuth").autocomplete({
            source:items,
            label:items.id,
            value:items.value
    })
    });
});
```